# Flutter Gradient with shadow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-design

How can I achieve this type of gradient, as shown in the image, along with a shadow on the top left corner? I've been trying, but I'm unable to add a shadow when specifying gradient values. Additionally, I want to apply the same gradient design with the following colors: Color(0xFFF8E048), Color(0xFF9C9CF8), and Color(0xff48F5CC).

[image]